# ToString Method Overriding in DataContract in WCF

Tags: wcf, datacontract

Even though i have overriden ToString method in the DataContract by returning ActivityType.Code property value in for class ActivityType. I'm still not geting the  ActivityType.Code property value on a client for binding the grid.can one let me know how the ToString method be available to Client.

Here is the code base

Data Contract

```
  [DataContract]
    public class Activity
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ActivityType ActivityTypeId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public EntityStatus Status { get; set; }

    }
    [DataContract]
    public enum EntityStatus
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Active = 0,
        [EnumMember]
        Inactive = 1
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ActivityType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (Code != null)
            {
                return Code.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Service Implementation

```
  public class TimeSheetManagementService : ITimeSheetManagementService
    {
        public List<BusinessEntities.Activity> GetActivities()
        {
            TimeSheetManagementDataController controller = new TimeSheetManagementDataController();


            var activities = controller.GetActivities();
            var activitiesresult = activities.Select(activity => new BusinessEntities.Activity()
                                                                     {
                                                                         ActivityTypeId =
                                                                             new BusinessEntities.ActivityType()
                                                                                 {
                                                                                     Code = activity.ActivityType.Code,
                                                                                     Description =
                                                                                         activity.ActivityType.
                                                                                         Description,
                                                                                     Name = activity.ActivityType.Name
                                                                                 },
                                                                         Code = activity.Code,
                                                                         Description = activity.Description,
                                                                         Status =  (EntityStatus)  Enum.Parse(typeof(EntityStatus),Convert.ToString((activity.Status==true)?1:0))
                                                                     });

            return activitiesresult.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Client Implementation

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="Code"/>

             <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="Description"/>

             <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="Status"/>

             <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="ActivityTypeId"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Output

```
  Code Description                   Status    ActivityTypeId
    ACT2    Requirement Feasibility Study Inactive TimeSheetManagementServiceRef.ActivityType
    ACT1    Requirement analysis    Inactive     TimeSheetManagementServiceRef.ActivityType
```

Comment: Duplicate question: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181039/wcf-datacontract-tostring-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133063/wcf-datacontract-class-with-methods

Comment: Thanks for the reference but those reference solution says we should be having proxy class ,but when i created the Service reference in the website project it just created XSD file, do i need to explicitly create the proxy class using SvcUtil.exe . Can't generate it using visual studio 2010 itself at the time of setting the service reference. Please suggest

Comment: I generally create a class library with those contracts and just reference this class library in both your service and your application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Data contract is for transporting data - not for transporting logic. When you use add service reference, add web reference, xsd.exe, wsdl.exe or svcutil.exe only properties are described - all your methods declared on server are lost. There are two ways to solve this:

- The ugly way: share the library with data contract between service and client instead of creating a new type on the client through one of the mentioned tools
- Those tools should create partial classes. Your `ToString` method obviously belongs to the client side because it is related to data presentation so create second partial part of the contract class on the client and declare `ToString` method in that class.